# (How) are fluid-templates preprocessed in Typo3

Tags: performance, typo3, template-engine, fluid

I'm looking for a performant already existing template-engine.
On my search there was one thing that made me curious:
The template-engine [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/what.is.smarty.tpl) generates php-scripts from the templates to optimize the performance.
Furthermore I looked at the template-engine fluid which is based on Typo3 and is used by the php-framework Flow3.

Now my question:
Is there a way similar to the way of the Smarty-engine to preprocess fluid-templates to get more performance?
Or how do systems working with fluid achieve good performance?

I hope you can help me because I found no answer (especially in the typo3-fluid-wiki).
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fluid templates are by default cached as PHP code, starting with TYPO3 4.6.

You will find all background informations on this on the blog of the developer of the caching, Sebastian Kurfürst:
http://sandstorm-media.de/blog/2011/07/31/fluid-static-php-caching.html

The official announcement (if it can be called like this) is in the [release notes of TYPO3 4.6](http://wiki.typo3.org/TYPO3_4.6#Fluid).

Apart from the [code of the complier](https://git.typo3.org/Packages/TYPO3.CMS.git/tree/HEAD:/typo3/sysext/fluid/Classes/Core/Compiler), I'm not aware of any other technical background information.

Comment: Thanks, that answers the question I asked.
But is there any information (beside the source-code) to learn how the precompiling works? Just some basic information?